# Encountered the symbol " " when expecting one of the following:

Tags: plsql

i have created a procedure to fine out whether a year is a leap year or not.i'm calling my procedure from an anonymous block.
This is my code

```
declare 
x number;
y number;
procedure leap(z IN number) IS
BEGIN
if(z%400=0)
then
dbms_output.put_line('leap year');
elsif(z%100=0)
then
dbms_output.put_line('not a leap year');
elsif(z%4=0)
then
dbms_output.put_line('leap year');
else
dbms_output.put_line('Not a year');
end if;
END;
BEGIN
y:=&y;
p1(y);
END;
```

I am getting these errors:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "400" when expecting one of the following:

type  
ORA-06550: line 9, column 9:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "100" when expecting one of the following:

type  
ORA-06550: line 12, column 9:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "4" when expecting one of the following:

type  
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
declare 
x number;
y number;
procedure leap(z IN number) IS
BEGIN
if REMAINDER(z,400)=0
then
dbms_output.put_line('leap year');
elsif REMAINDER(z,100)=0
then
dbms_output.put_line('not a leap year');
elsif REMAINDER(z,4)=0
then
dbms_output.put_line('leap year');
else
dbms_output.put_line('Not a year');
end if;
END;
BEGIN
y:=&y;
p1(y);
END;
```

Comment: Are you sure? Cause it works in my case. I am adding sqlfiddle link to the simplified version, so that you can see it yourself  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/cfbd6/39

Comment: i did,i'm getting this
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "400" when expecting one of the following:

   type <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier>

Comment: Are you getting this in sqlfiddle?

Comment: i am running in sql developer,and now i just copied it in sqlfiddle and i am getting the same error.

Comment: you can try yourself
declare 
x number;
y number;
procedure leap(z IN number) IS
BEGIN
if REMAINDER(z%400)=0
then
dbms_output.put_line('leap year');
elsif REMAINDER(z%100)=0
then
dbms_output.put_line('not a leap year');
elsif REMAINDER(z%4)=0
then
dbms_output.put_line('leap year');
else
dbms_output.put_line('Not a year');
end if;
END;
BEGIN
y:=&y;
p1(y);
END;

Comment: Well, you should run what I have posted as an answer, not your own version of it :) In my case, every z%some_number is changed to REMAINDER(z, some_number), but in your case to REMAINDER(z%some_number), which is an incorrect syntax for REMAINDER function.